# Determine Multiple values exist in column for same values in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, comparison

I am hoping someone can help me with a formula for the following:

[Excel hard data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYYpz.png)

My goal is to have an addition column return a yes or a no.
Yes if there are different values in column B for the same values in Column A.

The end would look something like this.

[Excel hard data, after formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxEQ3.png)

As you can see the formula would return "Yes" for lines 73,82 and 83 as the Number in Column A has different values in column B.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS,  if there are any that match on A but not B then it returns `Yes`:

```
 =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>" & B2),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: No need for that, a simple clicking of the check mark by the answer would be thanks enough.  Glad to have helped.  @Geoff